# Show that the graph of continuous function is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous and let $\Gamma =\{(x,f(x) \mid x \in \Bbb{R} \}$ so $\Gamma \subset \Bbb{R}^2$. Show that $\Gamma$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Define $h: \mathbb{R} \to \Gamma, h(x)=(x,f(x))$. This map is certainly continuous. What I would need to show is that it’s bijective and has continuous inverse. For the inverse I considered $h^{-1} : \Gamma \to \mathbb{R}, h^{-1}(x)=(x, f^{-1}(x))$, but I don’t have that $f$ necessarily would have an inverse? How can I find the inverse for this map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse mapping would simply be the projection of $(x,f(x)) \in \Gamma$ onto the $x$ axis since that's the reverse of your mapping, which "lifts" the $x$ axis to $(x,f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have the co-domain wrong in your putative inverse. You want $h^{-1}$ to take an ordered pair and give you a real number, but you have done the reverse.

Hint: consider $\pi(x, y) = x$.

Comment: $h^{-1}$ takes a ordered pair from the graph and outputs a real number?

Comment: @DanielLi Correct.